# how to make coturn run as user coturn

Tags: debian, coturn, turn

I have coturn running on a server and it runs as usual systemd process as user root.

Can someone tell me how I could make coturn run as user coturn ?

p.s. could someone modify the Tags and add coturn , turn and sturn because I need 300 reputation for this, and I have only 225-

Comment: (after checking): coturn on debian 9, available as a sysv init start script, starts as root (even if there appears to be some preliminary settings for user turnserver). coturn on Debian 10 runs as user turnserver. So does that mean you are running Debian 9 rather than Debian 10?

Comment: I run a Debian 9 but I'l check if I can upgrade coturn.

Comment: Don't try to mix a package from Debian 10 on Debian 9. I could see two options: backport the package(s) from buster to stretch, or just steal the coturn.service from buster and adapt it to stretch (if any needed at all). Oh and of course a 3rd option: upgrade the system to Debian 10.

Comment: Just noticed there's a coturn in stretch-backports already

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OP is running Debian 9. On Debian 9, the *coturn* package has a start script (only) available as sysv init script, and while the start scripts already takes some actions in relation to user *turnserver*, *coturn* is still run as *root*.

On Debian 10, while the same sysv script will probably behave the same, there's also a `coturn.service` file, which starts *coturn* with `User=turnserver` and `Group=turnserver`, so *systemd* will use it.

The good news is that there's already a [*stretch-backport*](https://packages.debian.org/stretch-backports/coturn) version of this package, currently version 4.5.1.0-1~bpo9+1. So one just has to add the *stretch-backports* repository and upgrade the *coturn* package, as documented there: https://backports.debian.org/Instructions/ (but using *stretch-backports* rather than *buster-backports*).

The service will then run as the dedicated user *turnserver*.

Comment: excellent, added backport version, everything rocks now

Comment: could you please add "coturn" and "turn" to the question tags, I do not have enough reputation to do it.